# How can I set a value to a "value"-type generic object?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I set a value to a "value"-type generic object?

My goal is to retrieve a column of scalar data and convert them into a list of integers.

Suppose, I have the following code snippet:

```
 public class DataAccess
 {
      SafeDataReader dataReader;

      public IList<Tcom> Get<Tcom>(ITransactionManager tm, string SQL, params object[] parameters)
      {
          T tempO = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

          Object objValue = dataReader.GetFieldValue(0);
          ... 
     }
     ...
}
```

Here, `T` can be either `value` types or `class` types.

- *I know how to set values to a `class`-type.*

But, say, T is a `value` type like `Int32`.

How can I set `objValue` to a `tempO`?

E.g.

```
TypeConverter tc = new TypeConverter();
tempO = (T) tc.ConvertTo(objValue, typeof(T));
```

gives an error:

```
 'TypeConverter' is unable to convert 'System.Int32' to 'System.Int32'.
```

---

Its usage can be

```
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(); 

    public IEnumerable<int> GetIDs()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> list = null;

        TransactionManager tm = new TransactionManager(DBNameConst.CurrentDB);

        try
        {
            tm.BeginTransaction();

            list = dataAccess.Get<int>(tm, @"select ID from AgeGroup");
            
            tm.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            tm.RollbackTransaction();

            throw;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

---

**Additional source code:**

```
class SafeDataReader
{

   private IDataReader reader = null;

   //...

    public virtual int? GetFieldValue(int columNo)
    {
        
        int? data = null;
        //int column = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);

        string columnName = reader.GetName(columNo);
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName)))
        {
            data = Convert.ToInt32(reader[columnName]);
        }

        return data;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Can you use [`GetFieldValue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfieldvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @devNull, No there is no such method in my framework.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, gives compile-time error.

Comment: `tempO = (Tcom)(tc.ConvertTo(objValue, typeof(Tcom)));` ?

Comment: But in general you should add error text if you have an error. Cause there are a lot of errors which compiler can give you.

Comment: @GuruStron, 'TypeConverter' is unable to convert 'System.Int32' to 'System.Int32'.

Comment: You need to add specific conditional checks for all the primitive types. `if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) { ... }`

Comment: @user366312 it does not look like a compile time error to me.

Comment: @GuruStron, sorry, that was my mistake. It was run-time error.

Comment: Have you tried simply `temp0 = (T)objValue`

Comment: _"that solved one part. but, see the edit"_ -- please don't. Ask one question at a time. If you have solved the current question, either delete the question or answer it. If you have a new problem to ask about **post a new question**. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285653/is-it-wrong-for-op-to-incorporate-suggested-changes-into-their-posted-code and many other related Q&A on Meta.